# Why doesn't my shell instance terminate when done with the batch script?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

Here is MCVE:

```
  /**
   * Get your program totally stuck in three simple steps:
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    /** 
     *  1. Create a simple batch file.
     */
    String batch = "echo Hello world!";
    File file = new File("hello_world.bat");
    file.createNewFile();
    try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file)) {
      out.print(batch);
    }
    /**
     * 2. Execute that batch file
     */
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/K "+file.getAbsolutePath()+">hello_world_log.txt");
    Process p = pb.start();
    /**
     * 3. Wait for the file like an idiot forever
     */
    p.waitFor();
  }
```

What I expect is that the `cmd.exe` process should terminate after the last command is executed. Instead it hangs out, doing literally nothing at all.

The contents of the log file are:

```
C:\...\testProject>echo Hello world! 
Hello world!
```

Comment: Use `/C` option instead of `/K`.

Comment: To expand on that: the `/K` option explicitly requests that `cmd.exe` remain running.  It's behaving exactly as documented.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't reading the output of the sub-process, maybe it's hung waiting for you to read stdin?

Take a look at [redirecting output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput-java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect-)

Comment: They don't really check.  They just write to the output stream and that stream will block if nothing reads from it.